# Can you define the data type for fields inside an excel export with php only when using the drupal webform module?

Tags: php, drupal, export-to-excel, drupal-webform

I am using the drupal [webform module](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!includes!webform.export.inc/7) and a custom module which alters submission data and labels before put inside the excel export file. At certain fields though MS Excel formats the data, so phone numbers become formulas and integers starting with a 0 are chopped.

I know there is phpexcel which might be capable of defining the data/format type of each field, but I wonder if this is also possible with what I already have: the webform export class/ simple php.

Here is the current code:

```
function mymodule_webform_results_export($node, $format = 'delimited', $options = array()) {
    global $user;
    module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.export');
    module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.components');

    // Open a new Webform exporter object.
    $exporter = webform_export_create_handler($format, $options);

    $file_name = drupal_tempnam('temporary://', 'webform_');
    $handle = @fopen($file_name, 'w'); // The @ suppresses errors.
    $exporter->bof($handle);

    [...]

    // Add the closing bytes.
    $exporter->eof($handle);

    // Close the file.
    @fclose($handle);

    $export_info['options'] = $options;
    $export_info['file_name'] = $file_name;
    $export_info['exporter'] = $exporter;
    $export_info['row_count'] = $row_count;
    $export_info['last_sid'] = $sid;

    return $export_info;
}
```

[Here is the original webform function.](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!includes!webform.report.inc/function/webform_results_export/7)